# Solving JVM "Incompatible object argument for function call" error (javassist instrumentation)

Tags: java, jvm, javassist

I'm having JVM (1.6.0b33) throw java.lang.VerifyError (Incompatible object argument for function call) on one of my classes. The class was instrumented (just this one method) with javassist (using CtMethod.make())

Is there a way for me to find which method call triggers the error? I walked through the output of javap -c -s -l but I just don't see anything wrong with any of the invocation instructions.

If anybody knows how to ask JVM to provide more detail (code address would be nice) about where this error is detected, for example, would be enough, so I knew where to focus. I can post the output of javap if someone wants to take a crack at it that way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out after examining JVM sources.

The error (Incompatible object argument for function call) means that the object **on which** the invocation is performed doesn't match the expected (by method signature) type (I assumed it had something to do with object arguments, but you get a slightly different error in that case).

Apparently, javassist doesn't insert proper instructions when you assign an object to an object of another class (alternatively it can fail the statement).

Javassist will take the following code as valid:

```
Object x ...;
String s = x; // javac requires cast here, javassist doesn't
s.isEmpty();
```

normally compiles into:

```
1 aload_1 // push x on stack
2 checkcast java/lang/String // check we can fit x into s
3 astore 2 // s = x;
4 aload 2 // 'this' for isEmpty()
5 invokevirtual String.isEmpty() // stack top used as 'this'
```

javassist (at least the version that I have) just doesn't add **checkcast** instruction, and the VM has no guarantee that at the time **invokevirtual** is called the stack top contains String, which is required because the **invokvirtual** is invoking a method from String class.

Remedy would be:

- use explicit cast in assignments
- fix javassist
- use local variables of explicit type